# Determinants and bilinear forms

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-algebra

If one calculates the product of diagonal elements of the $U$ matrix in a $LUP$ factorization of a given matrix $A$, one can calculate the determinant of $A$. Also it is known that $LUP$ factorization can be reduced to a series of matrix multiplications which are bilinear forms. Does that mean determinant calculation (multilinear form) can be reduced to a bilinear calculation?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is bilinear calculation?  (I know what a bilinear form is.)

Comment: Hi Tusyoshi I was implying the same.

Comment: Obviously the deterinant is not a bilinear form in the elements of the matrix (no matter how you divide the elements into two sets), if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Tsuyoshi. Yes I know that determinant is a multilinear form. However using only a sequence of matrix multiplications one can reduce to $LUP$. From which taking the product of diagonals of $U$ suffice to find the determinant. Multiplication is a bilinear map. I was curious then may be the determinant is actually a product of bilinear forms.

Comment: I feel this is just a tautological question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because (equivalently) determinants can be computed via row reduction.  Those steps exploit only the bilinearity and the antisymmetry of the determinant.